# How to modify default local JWT authentication in dot net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have jwt authentication in my application,
this is how i implemented in my startup.cs class

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII
                        .GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value)),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };

            });
```

inside Configure method

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

in controllers used attribute

```
[Authorize]
```

Normal authentication works fine.
I want to check some custom things when authenticating without losing the default authentication process, what I mean by that I don't want to write my whole new authentication method.

Comment: I guess you need to implement the middleware yourself. This post might be helpful: https://andrewlock.net/a-look-behind-the-jwt-bearer-authentication-middleware-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: any other way to override?

Comment: Can you describe *some custom things* in more detail? There are a few ways to approach this, but it depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @KirkLarkin I want to read a claim from token and check if it still valid.

Comment: well I have implemented it by using filter

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to build on top the default authentication by just chaining authentication schemes.

Firstly, you can implement custom authentication handler:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<CustomAuthHandlerOptions>
{
    public CustomAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<CustomAuthHandlerOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        //Write custom logic here
        return await Context.AuthenticateAsync(Scheme.Name);
    }
}

public class CustomAuthHandlerOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
{
    public string MyCustomOptionsProp { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can add the scheme to the `AuthenticationBuilder`:

```
        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII
                        .GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value)),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };

            })
            .AddScheme<CustomAuthHandlerOptions, CustomAuthenticationHandler>("CustomAuthJwt", options =>
                {
                    options.MyCustomOptionsProp = "Custom Value";
                });
```

I haven't actually tested this, but I know the idea of this approach works because it has been implemented in the [IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation Nuget Package](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation). My example is just the most simple version of that.

Comment: i will check and get back